# Accessing laravel session data from outside authenticated user context

Tags: session, caching, laravel

In Laravel I would like to make some user/process alter the session data for another user.

I would use this for:

1 - Updating/invalidating a "notification" count for user (1) when some other user (2) performs an action that needs to be notified to the first user.

2 - Updating/invalidating a session variable from inside a job that was queued.

I could use the Cache for this but this data seems to belong to the user session.

Comment: I just did a project which required pushing real-time updates.  I used sockets and long-polling to do it, but if you have redis or memcache, you could store the notifications and just use long-polling to continually check for updates and when it finds one, it displays it to the user.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have looked for some information regarding long-polling too. Have you accomplished that with laravel? I believe long-polling involves leaving open sockets between the client and the server and that doesn't seem like an easy thing to do in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Session::reflash()** and **Session::keep()**, to save and view sessions by another requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think this is what I am looking for.
What I am trying to do is to make a user/process change another user session data.